# Where count is exact not more or less mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have `one_to_many` relationship where i have 3 tables `images`, `items` and `image_items` .. every image may have one or many items, i wanna make a query where i pass the item/items id/ids and get a specific image (exactly one image) based on the count of items inside this image ...

Here is what i have tried so far but it has a problem, it gives me images with that count or more, i'm not sure if this logic or structure is valid in the first place:

```
SELECT `image_items`.`image_id`
FROM `image_items`
WHERE `image_items`.`item_id` IN(1, 2)
GROUP BY `image_items`.`image_id`
HAVING count(image_items.image_id) = 2
```

[image]

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97d6a1)

Lets say image (1) has items (1,2,3), image (2) has items (1,3) and image (3) has items (1,2) .. lets say i want the image that has exactly (1,2) .. with my query even with distinct it gives me images (1,3) when i want only image (3).

Comment: Sow us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: Can you try with `DISTINCT` as, `HAVING count(DISTINCT image_items.image_id) = 2` ?

Comment: @jarlh .. i have updated my question and explained exactly the desired result.

Comment: Please. No pictures. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry .. thank you, i did remove the pictures an kept the explanation of the desired result.

Comment: But you didn't read and/or act upon the information provided in the accepted answer to the linked question, which is a shame.

Comment: @Strawberry .. ok sorry, i hope its fine now.

Comment: @SherifSalah in your fiddle there is no image with items 1 and 2 only.

Comment: @forpas .. i'm sorry, my bad .. now image 4 has only (1,2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the WHERE clause and add in the HAVING clause a condition :

```
SELECT image_id
FROM image_items
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING 
  COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) = 2 
  AND
  SUM(item_id NOT IN (1, 2)) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ayzb2UB3Sibdkp7xpDWJgr/1).
Result:

```
| image_id |
| -------- |
| 4        |
```

Answer (score 1):

Forpas's solution is a good solution.  A slightly simpler `having` clause is:

```
SELECT image_id
FROM image_items
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY item_id) = '1,2';
```

If you are constructing this query in an application, this is simpler because you only need to pass in one value, the string `'1,2'`.

Comment: Its a marvelous solution, i'll probably use this one instead .. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need to use `DISTINCT` in the `HAVING` clause as `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT`image_id`) = 2` to get the exact count.

```
SELECT `image_id`
FROM `image_items`
WHERE `item_id` IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY `image_id`
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `image_id`) = 2
```

Comment: I've already tried that and it gives me all the images that has this exact count or more.